# Google Map v2 zoom-to-fit all markers AND Poly Lines

Tags: java, android, google-maps

So, I am showing a route from point A to point B on a Google Map on my Android App. This is all well. What I am doing now is zooming-to-fit both of the markers on the map by doing this:

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

for (LatLng marker : markerPoints) {
    builder.include(marker);
}

LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
int padding = 20; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,
        padding);
map.moveCamera(cu);
map.animateCamera(cu);
```

The problem is that this doesn't include poly lines, so if the route goes outside of the screen, it cuts off the poly line, like this:

[image]

Any ideas on how I can zoom-to-fit the poly lines? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

**I tried this code and its works good for me and also i attached output screen here.**

```
LatLng from_Latlng=new LatLng(11.9464816,79.8091988);
LatLng to_Latlong=new LatLng(12.9876327,80.1260089);

LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
builder.include(from_Latlng);
builder.include(to_Latlong);
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
GoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100), 2000, null);
```

**Output screen :-**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I got it. I just kept track of every LatLng within my Poly Line and added them to the LatLng builder

```
private class ParserTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(
            String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        String distance = "";
        String duration = "";

        if (result.size() < 1) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Points",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        // Traversing through all the routes
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                if (j == 0) { // Get distance from the list
                    distance = (String) point.get("distance");
                    continue;
                } else if (j == 1) { // Get duration from the list
                    duration = (String) point.get("duration");
                    continue;
                }

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(8);
            lineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);

        }

        tvDistanceDuration.setText("Distance:" + distance + ", Duration:"
                + duration);

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        map.addPolyline(lineOptions);

        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        /*
         * for (Marker marker : markers) {
         * builder.include(marker.getPosition()); }
         */
        for (LatLng point : points) {
            builder.include(point);
        }

        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        int padding = 20; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,
                padding);
        map.moveCamera(cu);
        map.animateCamera(cu, 2000, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. But either you move or animate the camera position. In your example you move already the camera to its position so it is not animation movement required to get to the position. In the case that you really want to animate the move to your LatLngBounds you should remove "map.moveCamera(cu"), otherwise remove the animateCamera call because it is not required.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that while you're building the polyline you keep track of the extents of the line.  Then when you zoom use those extents not the points.

Comment: Hm..this does make sense. Do you know of any way to keep track of those extents?

Comment: I got it working, I took your advice into consideration! Thanks

Comment: Can you share your answer @user1282637

Answer (score 2):

I copied from Premkumar's for mine. If you've got more than 2 points and you want to make sure everything fits (maybe you've got two points in the middle, and lots of stuff circling around). This solution works by creating a minLatLng and a maxLatLng and then using the newLatLngBounds solution from Premkumar's answer:

```kotlin
var minLat: Double? = null
var minLng: Double? = null
var maxLat: Double? = null
var maxLng: Double? = null
allLocs!!.forEach {
    if (minLat == null) {
        minLat = it.latitude
        maxLat = it.latitude
        minLng = it.longitude
        maxLng = it.longitude
    } else {
        minLat = min(it.latitude, minLat!!)
        maxLat = max(it.latitude, maxLat!!)
        minLng = min(it.longitude, minLng!!)
        maxLng = max(it.longitude, maxLng!!)
    }
}
val builder = LatLngBounds.builder()
builder.include(LatLng(minLat!!, minLng!!))
builder.include(LatLng(maxLat!!, maxLng!!))
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 100))
```

Obviously, if you need this in real time, it would be far more efficient to keep a tally of your mins and maxes every time you get a new location.